# Is it possible to setup a webhook in AWS that monitors a specific email address and can pass that received email information to Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, outlook, webhooks, amazon-ses

I am working on a project for a client where I need to monitor a specific email address.

When this email (Outlook) receives a message, I need to pass the email information (really only the attachment information) into a Lambda function which will then send the email attachment to be processed by Amazon Textract.

I am very confused on setting up this email "trigger".

So far all I have accomplished is that AWS SES is most likely the solution, but this service does not have much documentation for this use case.
I am reaching out here for either general or very specific advice on:

1. If this is feasible
2. How this can be accomplished using SES or some other AWS service

I am very new to AWS, but I understand how most of the services interact with each other.

Thank you to anyone who can provide insight on this.

Comment: Take a look at Graph, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible: create an Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) receiving rule and SNS topic and subscription, then create a new topic and subscribe to it using an AWS Lambda function as the endpoint.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-receive-and-process-incoming-email-with-amazon-ses/